# how to list and kill processes accessing internet in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, internet, process

How to kill the processes accessing Internet in background using terminal commands.
Command to stop (disconnect) the processes accessing Internet.
Command to kill the process accessing Internet.

Comment: kill -9 'name_of_program_using_internet'

Comment: @Nicholi : But how to find processes accessing internet ?

Comment: kill -15 is preferable, since programs designed to respond to the 15 argument will clean up before ending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find any processes making/listening for Internet connections run:

```
lsof -i
```

Output will be similar to this:

```
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd       4236   root    3u  IPv4   13169      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
ntpd       4260    ntp   16u  IPv4   13192      0t0  UDP *:ntp 
ntpd       4260    ntp   17u  IPv4   13196      0t0  UDP localhost:ntp 
ntpd       4260    ntp   18u  IPv4   13197      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.2:ntp 
master     4431   root   12u  IPv4   13397      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)
httpd2-pr  4493   root    3u  IPv4   13542      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Now use `kill` with the PID of the processes as listed above, for example, to kill `ssh` above, run:

```
sudo kill -15 4236
```

If that doesn't help, run:

```
sudo kill -9 4236
```

Option `-15` sends a `TERM` signal, which kindly asks the process to quit. Option `-9` sends a `KILL` signal, which forces the process to immediately quit. Try `-15` first, then `-9`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have [`ss`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) ([iproute2 package](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2)). For e.g. `ss -tup` will show all TCP and UDP sockets including the corresponding processes.

> `ss` is used to dump socket statistics. It allows showing
> information similar to netstat.  It can display more TCP and
> state information than other tools.